# Download failed using get_ssurgo in R from FedData package

Tags: r, gis

I am unable to download a large SSURGO dataset using the FedData package in R. I get the same error using the example code from the package:

```
vepPolygon <- polygon_from_extent(raster::extent(672800,740000,4102000,4170000), 
                                  proj4string='+proj=utm +datum=NAD83 +zone=12')

# Get the NRCS SSURGO data (USA ONLY)
SSURGO.VEPIIN <- get_ssurgo(template=vepPolygon, label='VEPIIN')
```

produces the error:

```
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "Download of https://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/Spatial/SDMNAD83Geographic.wfs?Service=WFS&Version=1.0.0&Request=GetFeature&Typename=SurveyAreaPoly&BBOX=-109.056777043215,37.033556543269,-108.279725827617,37.6609211495406 failed!"
```

It does work if I use extremely small templates, like 20'x20', but my understaning is that this package is supposed to enable larger downloads. Has something changed with the web soil survey since this package was created?

Comment: I also tried a similar approach using the mapunit_geom_by_11_bbox() function from the soilDB package and also got an error (500 internal server error), even using the example data given in the guide here: http://ncss-tech.github.io/AQP/soilDB/soilDB-Intro.html